# Search and Replace within a string

Tags: c#, replace

I have a string as below.

```
string data = "A := B;\nC:=D";
```

The string has to be replaced with `SET` statement as below.

```
data = "SET A=B;\nSET C=D"
```

It should replace `:=` with =`and insert a`SET` statement.

I came out with an algorithm as below but it's not working when I have multiple `:=`.

Is there any other easiest and efficient way to handle this? Perhaps using RegEx?

```
private string AddSETStatement(string script)
{
        script = script.Replace(": =", ":=");
        script = script.Replace(":=", ":= ");
        script = script.Replace(" :=", ":= ");
        int found = script.IndexOf(":=");
        while (found > -1)
        {
            int foundspace = -1;
            for (int index = found; index >= 0; index--)
            {
                string temp = script.Substring(index, 1);
                if (temp == " ")
                {
                    foundspace = index;
                    break;
                }
            }
            script = script.Remove(found, 1);
            if (foundspace == -1)
            {
                script = "SET " + script;
            }
            else
            {
                script = script.Insert(foundspace, " SET ");
            }
            found = script.IndexOf(":=");
        }

        return script.Trim();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please just use necessary tags. This has nothing to do with Visual Studio 2010, and it's not specific to C# 3.0 or 4.0. It's a generic C# string replacement question, and unnecessary tags just add noise that isn't helpful. Thanks. :)

Comment: Is the input known to be well formed? That is, is it guaranteed that you'll never have something like ":= random stuff here :==="? Also, what do you know abut the variables that precede and follow the `:=`? Are they always going to be one character long?

Comment: @Ken , sorry about that. Still quite new to stack overflow

Comment: @Kshitij, The input will be always ":="

Comment: @balan, no problem. Just info for future reference. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested this and I think this is the command that matches your requirement as you've coded your algorithm (which can be replaced with one line of code):

```
script = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(script, 
     @"([A-Z]{1})[\s]{0,1}:[\s]{0,1}=[\s]{0,1}([A-Z]{1})", "SET $1=$2", 
     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Just in case you actually use more than one space between and around := you can use this instead:

```
script = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(script,
     @"([A-Z]{1})[\s]*:[\s]*=[\s]*([A-Z]{1})", "SET $1=$2", 
     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

This turns this:

```
A := B;
C:=D
    E: =F
G : = H
  I   :   =   K;
```

Into this:

```
SET A=B;
SET C=D
    SET E=F
SET G=H
  SET I=K;
```

And one more which handles variable names that are bother upper and lower case and contain numbers:

```
script = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(script,
     @"([A-Za-z0-9]+)[\s]*:[\s]*=[\s]*([A-Za-z0-9]{1})", "SET $1=$2", 
     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Turns this:

```
Alpha1 := Bravo2;
Char3le:=Delta9
    E1ch3: =Foxt343
golf : = h1
  I3   :   =   k;
```

Into:

```
SET Alpha1=Bravo2;
SET Char3le=Delta9
    SET E1ch3=Foxt343
SET golf=h1
  SET I3=k;
```

At least one those or a combination of those should be able to do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Very simply...

```
data = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(data, "(^|\\n)", "$1SET ");
```

Comment: I'm not sure this works. Where does your solution replace variations of `:=` with `=`?

Comment: @balan, if you add the following to Diego's answer, you should be able to get what you want:  `data = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(data, @"(\s*:\s*=\s*)", "=");`. I'm no expert on regex so I am hoping that someone can chime in on a better regex.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, with a fairly "strict" regex:

```
Regex.Replace("A := B;\nC:=D", 
  @"(?<=(;|^)(\n|\s)*)(?<var1>\w+)\s*:=\s*(?<var2>\w+)\s*(?=;|$)",
  "SET $1=$2",
  RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture)
```

Explanation of the regex:

```
(?<=  # after: 
    (;|^)     # a semicolon or the start of the string
    (\n|\s)*) # and optional whitespace/newlines

(?<var1>\w+) # variable name - capture it into group "var1"
\s*          # optional whitespace
:=           # ":="
\s*          # optional whitespace
(?<var2>\w+) # second variable - capture it into group "var2"
\s*          # optional whitespace

(?=   # followed by:
    ;|$)  # either a semicolon or the end of the string
```